# How to reset security questions if I forgot them

Tags: security, apple-id, password

I've forgotten security questions to my account and I want to reset them. I've logged into my Apple ID, went to security section, and went ahead and clicked the link which says "Reset security questions?" in case I've forgotten it, which is my case.

I've entered my password, and it is asking for the answers of the  very security questions that I'm trying to reset. What is the point of asking the answers after clicking the link to reset them in the case that I've forgotten it?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't remember your answers ...

Have a look at: [If you forgot the answers to your Apple ID security questions](https://support.apple.com/HT201485)

At [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com), follow the onscreen steps to verify your identity. If you don't get any options to verify your identity, you can't reset your security questions at this time.

Choose new security questions and answers and select Continue.

**If you need more help, contact Apple Support**

Answer (score 12):

The following is a way that - seemingly - not even Apple Support knows about, I've found it myself after I got told that my account's situation is hopeless and I cannot get it back.

I forgot the answers to all of my security questions and did not have a rescue email. There is no way to reset the questions in that scenario, your only option is to get rid of the questions altogether - and you can do that by enabling two-factor authentication. The catch is that you must answer some security questions to enable it from Settings.

And here is the interesting part: if you **log in with your Apple ID on a device** (I did it with an iPhone 5 running iOS 10, but any iOS 10+/macOS 10.12+ device should work), **log out** and do that several times, you'll eventually get a popup to enable 2FA... and it will let you do that **without answering a single security question**! I got the popup after logging in and out just once, but your results may vary.

Note: if you have macOS, you can use this method without logging out from your main account on your device - just create a new user, log in, and you'll be asked to link your iCloud account. ([thanks for the tip, kallax!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/260831/how-to-reset-security-questions-if-i-forgot-them/347563#comment660106_347563))

---

Others have confirmed that this method still works in March 2021:

> I had a very old Apple ID with remaining credit that was only used for iTunes and not yet activated for iCloud. I had already changed the password via the email address some time ago. But resetting the security questions was not possible anymore, because I could not answer enough questions for that. And after several attempts even this form was blocked for the meantime.

> On an old iPhone 4s (iOS 9.3.6) the Apple ID was still stored under iTunes & App Store (I don't know if it is required to use a device which was already linked to this Apple ID). I also entered the same Apple ID under iCloud to activate iCloud for this Apple ID. I then entered my phone number under iCloud > Apple ID > Contact information (confirmed by code from SMS). Entering an additional email adress was at this stage not possible. Thereafter, under iCloud > Apple ID > Password & Security, the two-factor authentication could be enabled for the same phone number (eventually an unlock code has to be set prior under Settings). I had to confirm the activation via the code sent by SMS. Logging in to icloud.com was then possible again and I was able to update all account information.

Comment: I tried this. After 10 successful sign-in attempts: nothing. iPad running iOS 12.4.1.

Comment: @canton7 I'm sorry to hear that. Try to use a different device and see whether it works there. Also, this might've been fixed by Apple, I'm not sure.

Comment: I suspect Apple have probably addressed this, which is why I left a comment advising others that they might not have your luck any more!

Comment: @canton7 I can confirm that this "exploit" still works on iPhone 6 running iOS 12. I also managed to trigger the special 2FA pop-up in just 1 try. 

I was locked out of my Apple ID because I forgot the answers to my security questions and I had no other verification method. I can confirm that this solved my problem. Thanks @TamásSengel!

Comment: My Lord and Saviour. It worked I just logged out the AppleID of one of the office devices and signed in with my developer AppleID and as I signed in it asked me for a phone number. Then it send me the code to that number. Saved me from making a new account.

Comment: You saved me! I am an iOS Dev and Apply locked me out of an account that manages an app with more than 1 million users. Your workaround worked on my iPhone 6 running iOS12.

Comment: Confirmed that this method can work in March of 2021, with a caveat: I had to use an older version of macOS (El Capitan in my case). Mojave would not let me around the security questions no matter what. Also, I had to add a valid credit card to my account through the iCloud Account Details pane. After doing that (and verifying my phone number) I was able to force 2FA through, even after Apple Support was unable to help, and do away with those Security Questions once and for all.

Comment: These stories bring me joy, I'm glad my solution worked for you!

Comment: Worked for me today - logged in for the first time on a MacBook Air running Sierra 10.12.6 and it asked if I wanted to set up 2FA during the iCloud login process. Had a credit card and phone number set up already.

Comment: Still works for me today. I didn't have 2FA. Apple told me I have wrong answers to one or more security questions. Their reps could not help. A week ago I replaced my expired credit card and today logged into one of my old Apple ID's, on my iPad running 13.6.1. On first login attempt I was prompted to enable 2FA. Thank you.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!! Thank you very much. Apple support said that there is nothing they can do. 

Log in to your account on any Apple Device and in security settings add phone number as 2FA number. Once this is done, you can log in to your account using website as it will ask you about SMS code and not those stupid security questions.

Comment: Note if you have the password you don't even need 2FA or a phone number for this to work. I had an old account where I never set security questions and the recovery email no longer existed. It still asked for questions (i never selected) whenever logging into appleid.apple.com. They said they couldn't help, as I didn't have a device. Pulled out old 5S, no SIM. Reset, added my apple ID with my password. In security settings, it prompted for questions, said i forget, it let me select "Device" as reset option. pushed a code to device, code let me reset to new questions. Terrible security model.

Comment: Maybe would be useful to mention that if you have macOS, you can use this method without logging out from your main account on your device, just create new user on your macOS, log in, and you'll be asked to link your iCloud account. After entering email and password I was asked to link my phone number for 2FA  Thank you! I almost started to rip hair out of my head when Apple asked to enter answer for security questions to recover security questions.

Comment: @kallax Awesome bit of information, thank you! I've added it to the answer.

Comment: @NickJ Awesome! This method might deserve its own answer.